# MSBuild(vsproj) setting for coping all target files to the specify folder before building

Tags: android, visual-studio, msbuild, xamarin.android, csproj

My environment is Visual Studio 2017(15.5.5) / Xamarin for Android.

I want to copy and update "Assets" files from another folder(in this case, all files under "../crossplat/" folder) before building automatically because those files are sharing for other platform projects.

```
\COPYTEST
├─crossplat
│  │  text1.txt
│  │
│  └─sub
│      │
│      └─sub2
│          │
│          └─sub3
│
└─project
    │  MainActivity.cs
    │  xa.csproj
    │  xa.sln
    │
    ├─Assets                      // !Destination folder
    ├─Properties
    │      AndroidManifest.xml
    │      AssemblyInfo.cs
    │
    └─Resources
        │  Resource.Designer.cs
```

(Sample project is at [OneDrive](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ak0LcIIOu-p0jVvnuzE84T1HQlGN))

For that reason, I added properties to the .csproj file with reference to MSDN and StackOverflow's answers, but of course my knowledge is insufficient and it doesn't work.

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
      <CrossFiles Include="..\clossplat\**\*.*" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(CrossFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(ProjectDir)Assets\%(RecursiveDir)" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
    <ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="Assets\**">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

Please tell me the appropriate way to carry out this procedure.

Answer (score 0):

> MSBuild(vsproj) setting for coping all target files to the specify folder before building

Sorry for the late reply, but hope this answer can give you some help.

After test your target, I found there are two errors in your target, everything is work after correcting them.

First, you should **set this target at the very end of the project**, just **before** the end-tag `</Project>`, **after** the import:

```
 <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets" />
```

Second, **error path in your target**. You are suing following scripts to list the files in the target:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <CrossFiles Include="..\clossplat\**\*.*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

However, I have found that you folder name is **crossplat** rather than **clossplat** ("**l**" instead of "**r**"). So VS/MSBuild will not find the files.

After correcting those two error, this target works fine:

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
      <CrossFiles Include="..\crossplat\**\*.*" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Copy SourceFiles="@(CrossFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(ProjectDir)Assets\%(RecursiveDir)" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />

    <ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="Assets\**">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </Content>
    </ItemGroup>

  </Target>

</Project>
```

The output:

[image]